# Tomcat can't locate the keystore file

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have this configuration in my server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="C:\www6.domain.com.jks"
           keystorePass="uatweb" 
           keyAlias="www6.domain.com.jks" />
```

However, I get error that tomcat can't find the file even if the file is in fact in the path I specified.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:385)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:291)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:549)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:489)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:434)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the name of `keystore` file ? is it exist in `c:\` ?

Comment: Have you tried `C:\\www6.domain.com.jks`?

Comment: @user3145373ツ yes, it exists there. www6.domain.com.jks is the name of the file.

Comment: @MikeLaren Haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Don't mess around with backslashes. Use a forward slash.